# curtain drop down effect ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I was hoping ion slide box from ionic would have the option of sliding down a view like a curtain but it does not.

I was using slide box but do not mind having a new view .But I am pretty clueless about having this effect.

How do I allow a user to get a view by sliding it down from top to bottom and then allow the user to slide it back up and show the previous view as is.

I am aware of Swiper but it does not look very neat to me.

Answer (score 1):

here is a control that was written to pull up a view from the bottom of the window.

http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-pullup/

the developer might have something that could help you make minor mods to get it to pull down from top of view?